# Table is not getting created in spring boot 3 with Flyway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

Table is not getting created in spring boot 3 with Flyway.

I am trying to create the table and insert some data through migration on initial load but my table is not getting created.

Only the flyway_schema_history is getting created.

Here is pom xml.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

In my application xml I am giving the flyway config you can find it here,

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: "${MYSQL_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb}”
    username: "${MYSQL_USERNAME:root}"
    password: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}"
  flyway:
      enabled: true
      baseline-on-migrate: true
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT property_key, property_value FROM properties WHERE application = ? and profile = ? and label = ?
          order : 1
        encrypt:
          enabled: true
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
server:
  port: 8088

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

And In my **resource/db/migration/V1__Create_Properties.sql**

I am creating table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS properties (
    properties_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    application VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    profile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    label VARCHAR(255),
    property_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    property_value TEXT,
    UNIQUE KEY unique_property (application, profile, label, property_key)
);
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing here.